# Append not working in php/ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, printing

I am using a standard example of a chatbox (http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/3213/post/1-Tutorial-on-Creating-an-AJAX-based-Chat-system-in-PHP.html) with *jQuery 1.7*. Everytime I submit I get the message

> Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

The input message is still send to the database and processed correctly, however the "append" to the original source and thus the printing on screen does not work. How can I make this work and prevent the message? My main.js is here:

var lastTimeID = 0;

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSend').click( function() {
      sendChatText();
      $('#chatInput').val("");
    });
    startChat();
  });

  function startChat(){
    setInterval( function() { getChatText(); }, 1000);
  }

  function getChatText() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/taboo/game/refresh.php?lastTimeID=" + lastTimeID
    }).done( function( data )
    {
      var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
      var jsonLength = jsonData.results.length;
      var html = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
        var result = jsonData.results[i];
        html += '<div ' + result.role + '">(' + result.mes_time + ') <b>' + result.username +'</b>: ' + result.message + '</div>';
        lastTimeID = result.messageID;
      }
        $("#reply").append(html);

    });
  }

  function sendChatText(){
    var chatInput = $('#chatInput').val();
    if(chatInput != ""){
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/taboo/game/submit.php?chattext=" + encodeURIComponent( chatInput )
      });
    } 
  }
```

Here the edited version after the first comments:
    var lastTimeID = 0;

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#btnSend').click( function() {
        sendChatText();
        $('#chatInput').val("");
      });
      startChat();
    });

    function startChat(){
      setInterval( function() { getChatText(); }, 1000);
    }

    function getChatText() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/taboo/game/refresh.php?lastTimeID=" + lastTimeID,
        success: function( data   ){
          var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
          var jsonLength = jsonData.results.length;
          var html = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
            var result = jsonData.results[i];
            html += '<div ' + result.role + '">(' + result.mes_time + ') <b>' + result.username +'</b>: ' + result.message + '</div>';
            lastTimeID = result.messageID;
          }
            $("#reply").append("<p>Hello</p>");
            console.log(html);
            console.log("H");
        }
    });
    }

    function sendChatText(){
      var chatInput = $('#chatInput').val();
      if(chatInput != ""){
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/taboo/game/submit.php?chattext=" + encodeURIComponent( chatInput )
        });
      } 
    }
```

This is where the input comes from:

```
                <div class="reply" id="response"></div>
                    <div id="ajaxForm">
                      <input type="text" id="chatInput" /><input type="button" value="Send" id="btnSend" />
                    </div>
```

This is the DB connection:

```
      class chatClass
      {
        public static function getRestChatLines($messageID)
        {
          $arr = array();
          $jsonData = '{"results":[';
          include "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/taboo/game/connectToDB.php";
          $_db->query("SET NAMES utf8"); 
          $statement = $_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_id > ? and mes_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)");
          $statement->bindParam('i', $messageID);
          $statement->execute(array($messageID));
            while ($statement->fetch()) {
              $line->message_id = $messageID;
              $line->game_id =$gameID;
              $line->user_name = $username;
              $line->role = $role;
              $line->message = $message;
              $line->ordering = $ordering;
              $line->mes_time = date('H:i:s', strtotime($mes_time));
              $arr[] = json_encode($line);
          }
          $link = null;
          $jsonData .= implode(",", $arr);
          $jsonData .= ']}';
          return $jsonData;
        }

        public static function setChatLines($message, $username, $role, $gameID, $ordering) {
          include "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/taboo/game/connectToDB.php";
          $statement = $_db->prepare( "INSERT INTO messages(message, user_name, role, game_id, $ordering) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?,)");
          $statement->execute(array($message, $username, $role, $gameID, $ordering));
          $link = null;
        }
      }
    ?>
```

And the submit in the middle that passes the data from the main.js (first code) to the DB php (just before this).

```
<?php
      session_start();
      require_once( "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/taboo/game/connectToDB.php" );
      require_once( "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/taboo/game/chatClass.php" );
      $message = htmlspecialchars( $_GET['chattext'] );
      echo $message;
      $username=$_SESSION['username'];
      $ordering = $_SESSION['ordering'];
      ++$ordering; 
      $_SESSION['ordering'] = $ordering;
      chatClass::setChatLines( $message, $username, $_SESSION['role'], $_SESSION['gameID'], $ordering);
    ?>
```

This is the refresh that updates and checks for updates periodically.

```
<?php
              require_once( "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/taboo/game/connectToDB.php" );
              require_once( "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/taboo/game/chatClass.php" );
              $message_id = intval( $_GET[ 'lastTimeID' ] );
              $jsonData = chatClass::getRestChatLines( $message_id );
              print $jsonData;
            ?>
```

Those are all elements related to the chatbox that doesn't work.
Thanks in advance for your help - I have been trying everything I could find in this forum and others and nothing gets my text returned to the bowerser

Comment: Where is the line that uses `getPreventDefault()`?

Comment: I have no line that uses the method and I also have no import .js or anything that uses the line.

Comment: Well the console error should provide the line of where that error occurs, no?

Comment: I have tried to change the jQuery version (seems to be a bug in some), include the method under $(document), use all potential variations of return, print, append, and appendTo but nothing stops the error and nothing gets the text printed. Please help...

Comment: " jquery-1.7.js:3506:" console output - not very helpful.

Comment: Oh you are using jQuery 1.7? Can you update that to a new version? That is pretty old.

Comment: Error also occurs with earlier versions of jQuery...

Comment: Yeah, can you not uses a newer jQuery? Then for the `getChat()`, why use `done()`? Can't you just use the `success:` ?

Comment: Thanks! The error is gone but it still does not append the text to the class element reply in my index.php.

Comment: Have you tried using the `success:` instead of `done()`?

Comment: "getChat()" should parse the Json that is returned from the DB and "append" the parsed text to the class #reply, a chatbox that should display all the written messages.

Comment: Yeah do that in the `success: function(data) { code here }` Try that. Also try `console.log(data);` see what is returned.

Comment: What is `'<div ' + result.role + '">('` supposed to be?

Comment: I replaced ".done(" by ".success:" and added console.log but now the function does not do anything anymore at all. So no console data and no more writing into db...

Comment: The "<div..." is for building an html response that is then appended at the end of the function. Those are my data from the db - the role of the user, the message that was sent... Can you not use it like this? Sorry, I'm fairly new to php...

Comment: No you do `$.ajax({ type: "GET",  url: "/game/refresh.php?lastTimeID=" + lastTimeID, success: function(data) {code here} });`

Comment: Thanks ok... its running, but still doesn't append or print. Nothing special in the log - submit called, refresh called to refresh the page... no errors and unfortunately no printing. Already tried "append("Hi")" and append ("<p>Hi</p>") instead of html and does not work...

Comment: Do you have any more suggestions? I send the message now to db to get other details and to make sure its only the last few messages displayed. Could I instead print it directly? How?

Comment: Does `#reply` element exist?

Comment: Does anything return on `console.log(data);` ? Does it return something?

Comment: This is the elements it is supposed to append to:

Comment: <div class="reply" id="response"></div>
         <div id="ajaxForm">
           <input type="text" id="chatInput" /><input type="button" value="Send" id="btnSend" />
         </div>

Comment: if I add console.log(something/mydata) instead of append it does nothing. I also tried to not use the startMethod and just print data there - somehow I just cannot get the messages to appear in the browser... please help, have been trying for hours

Comment: Do an edit, lets see what you have so far for `getChatText()`. Don't replace what's in the question, just add a new part with what you have now.

Comment: Also add your php for that ajax all in the edit.

Comment: Thanks - that's all I got for the chatbox.

Comment: sorry - I realized that to late what you meant and replaced the original question.... I will post it again in a minute.

Comment: If you haven't already figured it out, you do need to have that `setInterval()` like you originally had so it can continually check.

Comment: Thanks Rasclatt - the problem is still that if I do that it sends the message to all users that are loggedin and not just the ones that are identified by the gameId in the specific session the message comes from... Do you maybe know how to change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#reply").append("<p>Hello</p>");
```

this will select element with id="reply"
but in your html
    
    
        
    
there are no `id="reply"`

you can append it by

```
$('#response').append("<p>Hello</p>")
```

this will select tag with `id="response"` and append the hello

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that as well and now again with your code and the changed ajax function but it still doesn't output anything. Any ideas?

Comment: can you verify that the `getChatText ajax.success` is being triggered and could you inspect to verify that the p tag is not appended ?

Comment: Ok -yes, it does send now, but only normal text - no html and unfortunately in a 2 second interval the same message.... if I add it to the first on click function instead to only get a message when one is submitted, it doesn't work again ;-( All I want to do is display the messages that are entered on the screen.... please help me once more

Comment: in your `startChat` remove the `setInterval`  and in `getChatText` you should clear the innerHTML of #response  use this instead `$('#response').html('').append("Insert your html here");`

Comment: Sorry, me again... I just realized that by this method the message only gets send to the user who send the message and not to the second user in the same session... the sessions are identified by game_id... do you perhaps know how to change it so that the message appears for all users in the session only? When I start the refresh again and append there it posts it to all users on the page and repeatedly...