# PHP/Ajax: return message to multi-user session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I am trying to create a multi-user application in which always two users are joined together into one session and play with each other. The joining is done by means of this:

```
            $string="?id=" . $gameID;
            $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/index.php' . $string;
            print "<script>document.location.href='$home_url' ;</script>";
```

One user might log in earlier then the other. All users in the application are automatically directed to a session where there is currently only one user, based on the DB entry. I want to enable them to exchange messages. The chat code is here: [Append not working in php/ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266742/append-not-working-in-php-ajax/37268449?noredirect=1#comment62064343_37268449)

It does append now but the problem is only to the one user the message came from. What do I have to do to enable the exchange? This is the last thing I need to have my application ready. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In this cases using PHP sessions are not good choice because it is accessible with one user, i suggest saving sessions data(session_id, data) on your database an it will be accessible with all users.

Comment: I do save the data in the database and join users based on that. The joining of users, the display of individual contents, etc. all work fine. The main question is how can I exchange messages between these two users? Thanks

Comment: each user have special session id(http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php), you can save messages according to those session id and exchange those.